Thinking about bad words while making wodu
My doubt is while making wodu I have this problem my mind keeps repeating bad words in mind does it mean I can continue making wodu or should start from beginning

assalam alaikom,if bad words or inappropriate thoughts come to your mind while making wudu (ablution), they do not invalidate your wudu. The key point is that wudu is invalidated by physical actions (such as breaking wind, relieving oneself, etc.), not by thoughts or whispers in your mind.
May Allah make it easy for you!
ALLAH KNOw BEST
